# uploading image from iphone with other data with validation using json wcf

Tags: c#, sql, json, wcf, image-uploading

i am creating a wcf for an iphone app. what i need is a POST where i will update the sql with image and other data. i know how to get data but im new in updating with image is there any examples i can brownse on and apply it to my project. there are lots of wcf uploading topic in the net but nothing is close to what i wanted. all i see is uploading to a specific folder. i need is uploading it to the sql. i dont have any idea about stream.

```
using System.ServiceModel; using System.ServiceModel.Web; using System.IO;  namespace RESTImageUpload {   
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IImageUpload
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "FileUpload{empid},{fileName}")]
        void FileUpload(string empid,string fileName, Stream fileStream);         

    }  }
```

Comment: that's a requirements description....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the following staff works(I upload a file from a razor view to a controller action and that action connects to a WCF service and passes the file as bytes)

your operation contract:

```
     [ServiceContract]
     public interface IService1
     {
        [OperationContract]
        string FileUpload(byte[]buffer);
     }
```

your service implementation file:

```
  public class Service1 : IService1
  {
    public string FileUpload(byte[] buffer)
    {
        using (var connection = 
               new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myCnnStr"].ToString()))
        {
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(
                    "INSERT INTO Images (ImageData) VALUES(@buffer)",
                    connection);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("buffer", buffer));              
            connection.Open();
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                // log exception
                return "fail";
            }
       }
        return "ok";
    }
 }
```

settings inside web.config file of the WCF application:

```
         <bindings>
           <basicHttpBinding>
             <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000000"></binding>
           </basicHttpBinding>
         </bindings>
```

your mvc controller that accepts file upload and calls the  WCF service function SaveFile

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        var client = new Service1Client();          
        var buffer = new byte[file.ContentLength];
        file.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, file.ContentLength);
        client.FileUpload(buffer);

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but i want to get the image from the iphone app and save to the sql

Comment: I don't think someone will give you full solution. Anyway I added code inside the WCF SaveFile function which'll let you save your image into a sql database. Also I assume that the ImageData column inside your database has varbinary as its DataType.